# Evaluate $I=\int_{\gamma (0,1)}\frac{zdz}{(z^2-4z+1)^2}$ using Taylor's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, contour-integration

I've shown that $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z^2-4z+1)^2}$ is holomorphic apart from at points $\alpha=2-\sqrt3$ and $\beta=2+\sqrt3$  and that the talyor coefficient of $g(z)=\frac{z}{(z-\beta)^2}$ centred at $\alpha$ is 
$$c_n=\frac{\alpha+n\beta}{(\beta-\alpha)^{n+2}}$$

Now I'm not sure how to use Taylor's theorem to evaluate the integral I, where $\gamma (0,1)$ is the unit circle centred at the origin
Thanks!

ADDITION
I can't seem to comment, but no, I don't think we've learnt residues. I have Cauchy's integral formula if that's similar?
Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. It's much much clearer now. I can't seem to upvote or select an answer though, any idea why this is?

Comment: Do you know about residues?

Comment: I read your response in the middle of typing my answer, so I decided to finish it anyway even though it uses residues

Comment: Updated with answer using only Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: I have no idea why you can't upvote or accept my answer, I will flag the question for moderator attention so they can look into it.

Comment: You can't upvote answers because your account is [not registered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562/214632) (though you should still be able to [_accept_ answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/214632) -- if you can't do this, something is surely wrong). To register your account I believe you go to your [user profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/109809/tim), click the "my logins" tab near the top, and then add a login.

Comment: @ArthurFischer He also can't comment, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes $\gamma(0,1)$ is $\gamma\colon [-\pi, \pi]\to \Bbb C, \theta \mapsto e^{i\theta}$.

The [Residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) yields $$\displaystyle\int_\gamma f=2\pi i\left(\operatorname{Res}(f,\alpha)+\operatorname{Res}(f,\beta)\cdot 0\right)=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,\alpha).$$

All that is left to find is $\operatorname{Res}(f,\alpha)$. You should know that $\operatorname{Res}(f,\alpha)$ is the coefficient of $(z-\alpha)^{-1}$ in the [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of $f$ in a set like $\{z\in \Bbb C\colon 0<|z-\alpha|<r\}$, for some $r>0$.

You've already found, for all $z$ in the set above,  $\displaystyle \dfrac z{(z-\beta)^2}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(c_n(z-\alpha)^n\right)$, thus

$$\dfrac{z}{(z^2-4z+1)^2}=\dfrac z{(z-\alpha)^2(z-\beta)^2}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(c_n(z-\alpha)^{n-2}\right).$$

Therefore the coefficient of $(z-\alpha)^{-1}$of $f$ in its Laurent series is $c_1\color{grey}{=\dfrac{4}{(2\sqrt 3)^3}=\dfrac{1}{6\sqrt 3}}.$ Which agrees with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Res%28z%2F%28z%5E2-4z%2B1%29%5E2%29).

Finally $\displaystyle\int_\gamma f=2\pi i\cdot \dfrac{1}{6\sqrt 3}=\dfrac{\pi i}{3\sqrt 3}$.

---

In this part of the answer I'm mainly following theorem 5.2.1 in [this](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/complex-analysis/complex_analysis.pdf) notes.

[Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_complex_analysis) (or perhaps just its proof, depending on the exact statement), says that in the series of $\varphi$ around $z_0$, $$\color{grey}{\varphi (z)=}\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(a_n(z-z_0)^n\right),$$ for each $n\in \Bbb N_0$, $a_n$ is given by $$\displaystyle \color{grey}{a_n=}\dfrac 1{2\pi i}\int_{C_r}\dfrac{\varphi (z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\mathrm dz.$$

Setting $n=1,\varphi =g$ and $z_0=\alpha$ gives us $\displaystyle \int _{C_1}f=2\pi i\cdot c_1=\dfrac{\pi i}{3\sqrt 3}$.